# When trying to deploy my Django app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I am getting the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config.settings'"

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to deploy my Django app on AWS, but I keep getting errors like those mentioned in the title. I've tried changing the structure of my directory without luck. The below image shows my django.config file, along with the structure of my file directory:

[Django Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dywhh.png)

my django.config file looks like

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: lexgen.config.wsgi:application
```

wsgi.py looks like

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I've tried changing my directory structure and moving references to config.settings, but that causes other parts of my program to break and create new error messages. Other answers I've read involve changing the django.config or wsgi.py files, in particular the WSGIPath in django.config, but I haven't been able to crack this just yet.

If anyone has any insight into this problem, I'd really appreciate it. Happy to include any other information that may help answer this question.